# Two seperate diff sessions on one screen

Tags: split, vimdiff

I would like to compare

- `File1-v1.txt` with `File1-v2.txt`

and

- `File2-v1.txt` with `File2-v2.txt`

at the same time. I tried to create the following layout:

```
+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |
|   File1-v1.txt  <=>  File1-v2.txt   |  // scroll synchronized diff
|                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+
|                  |                  |
|   File2-v1.txt  <=>  File2-v2.txt   |  // *another* scroll synchronized diff
|                  |                  |
+------------------+------------------+
```

What I get is a 4-way diff, where all four buffers were scroll-synchronozed and compared. That's cool, but it's not what I want in my special case.

How can I configure vim to show me two separate "2-way diff sessions" instead of the one 4-way diff?

PS
This would be particular useful when analysing Git history of two (or more) files.

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible. Regarding the 2-way/3-way/4-way diff, check [Splice plugin](https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim/).

Comment: You can use tabpages to view different sets of diffs, as diff are local to the current tab page. See `:h diff.txt`

Comment: @PeterRincker Using multiple tabs looks like acceptable workaround. At least, if using a single vim instance is a constraint. Would you like make an answer out of your suggestion?

Comment: alternatively, if you want exactly that layout and you don't mind having multiple Vim, you could have a tmux/screen split and two independant Vim instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tabpages to view different sets of diffs, as diff are local to the current tab page.

For more information see:

```
:h diff.txt
:h tabpage
:h gt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the terminal, for instance in konsole: `Ctrl-Shift-)`
Then in each terminal I'd make the corresponding diff.

Comment: This is a great idea and depending on the situation, it can be very helpful. But most of the time I prefer to have a single instance of vim per project. Thank you.